# How to calculate Frames per second in Qt Graphics Application

Tags: qt, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I have an Qt based OpenGLES2.0 application, where I want to capture the FPS.

my application draw same geometry for 16 times and then try to know the FPS.

How can I make sure `glDrawElements()` has finished its job ?

I want to get the correct FPS.

Is there any way to make the `glDrawElements()`synchronous or Pooling the `glDrawElements()` complete?

Comment: Do you intend to draw an animation? How do you update the scene? Can you show us some code (minimal working example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. define a Timer object in application window/widget  class.
   QTime frameTime;
2. Start the timer in initializeGL.
   frameTime.start();
3. in PaintGL

---

```
paintGL ()
{  
   draw_your_geometry();

   ++frameCount;

  if (frameTime.elapsed() >= 1000)
  {

     double fps = frameCount / ((double)frameTime.elapsed()/1000.0);

  }

}
```